# In JAVA, can float and double number subtracted by using big decimal

Tags: java, floating-point, double, bigdecimal

Here is the Code(i am giving fraction of code)
Below code is of withdraw of savings account:-

I have declared variables as below:-

```
protected static double balance;
protected static float amount;
```

So i opened account with balance as 7095, then i am performing withdraw operation, entering amount as 100.0. I am getting below results which is wrong. If i enter amount as 100, getting expecting results. Need help.

```
Total balance:- 7095
Withdraw amount:- 48
Current balance:- 7047
```

---

```
  BigDecimal amount3 = new BigDecimal(balance);
  BigDecimal amount4 = new BigDecimal(amount) ;
  System.out.println("Total balance" +amount3);
  System.out.println("Withdraw amount" + amount4);
  Object obj = new Object();
  obj = (amount3.subtract(amount4));
  System.out.println("Current balance" +obj);
```

Comment: I can't understand the problem

Comment: See the BigDecimal Javadoc regarding both constructors you're using. Try using the `String` constructors instead for a perfectly accurate representation of your numbers: `new BigDecimal(String.valueOf(amount));`

Comment: The problem is probably in the code that reads `amount`.

Comment: Unless this is a pet project **never ever** use floating point numbers to represent money. Floating point arithmetic is working with a lot of rounding and it is not precise enough for financial applications.

Answer (score 4):

Binary floating-point (`float` and `double` in Java) can only represent fractional numbers of a form counter-intuitive to base-10-using humans. The number 0.1 is famously not representable in binary floating-point, for instance.

The problem with binary floating-point is **not** addition and subtraction. The problem is the representation of (some) fractional numbers of interest to you, in particular, decimal numbers. Therefore, it will not help to convert to `BigDecimal` numbers that are already represented in binary floating-point. They have already been approximated at the instant it was chosen to represent them as `float` and `double`. Computing as accurately as you want won't erase the **representation error** that was made then.

If you care about representing decimal numbers exactly, do not use binary floating-point to store them. In other words, do not declare `amount` and `balance` with binary floating-point types `float` and `double`.

Comment: The docs say this too: " Notes: The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable. One might assume that writing new BigDecimal(0.1) in Java creates a BigDecimal which is exactly equal to 0.1 (an unscaled value of 1, with a scale of 1), but it is actually equal to 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. This is because 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a double (or, for that matter, as a binary fraction of any finite length). Thus, the value that is being passed in to the constructor is not exactly equal to 0.1, appearances notwithstanding". Too long a comment